# How to use Accelerometer in cocos2dx

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, accelerometer, cocos2d-android

I've been trying to get the acceleromter to work in cocos2d-x c++.
I tried to add this function to my scene which a lot of my Google search results said I should:

```
virtual void didAccelerate(Acceleration *acceleration);
```

That does however give me an error saying I'm overriding a final function.
Then I found how I could use the EventDispatcher thing for it.

```
    auto accListener = EventListenerAcceleration::create(CC_CALLBACK_2(MainScene::accelerated, this));
getEventDispatcher()->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(accListener, this);
```

In both of these I had called this function earlier in my scene's init function:

```
    setAccelerometerEnabled(true);
```

I'm all out of ideas and I need help. On the second "approach" it compiled, but my accelerated function was never called.

Thank you in advance!

I'm using Android so maybe I need to edit something in the AndroidManifest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The guys at the cocos forums linked me to this:
[Cocos docs](http://cocos2d-x.org/docs/programmers-guide/8/index.html#creating-an-accelerometer-event)

As you can see the correct way to go is to use the EventListener approach as described earlier. However you need to call

```
Device::setAccelerometerEnabled(true);
```

Calling

```
setAccelerometerEnabled(true);
```

From the scene's init doesn't work, you need to call the static method on 'Device'.

So here's how you do it.

```
Device::setAccelerometerEnabled(true);
auto accListener = EventListenerAcceleration::create(CC_CALLBACK_2(MainScene::accelerated, this));
getEventDispatcher()->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(accListener, this);
```

Where accelerated is takes these parameters:

```
void accelerated(Acceleration *acceleration, Event *event);
```

Of course this function can be called anything as the EventListener takes a function pointer.

Comment: Remember you wont get accelerator events in simulator, you need a device.

Answer (score 1):

Tritzium answered it right. Just wanted point out:
You wont get accelerator events in simulator, you need a device.